# emacs の非同期プロセスの、 process-status の更新タイミングは？

Tags: emacs, elisp

emacs の、非同期プロセスの process-status は、どのタイミングで更新されるのでしょう？ lisp コードが実行している最中に更新されうるものなのでしょうか？具体的には：

```
(defun some-func (process)
  (process-status process)
  ;; some work;
  ;; process は特に操作しない
  (process-status process))
```

のようなコードがあったときに、これら `process-status` の結果は、(process の非同期の状態変化により)変わりうるものなのでしょうか？
非同期プロセスを扱う elisp を記述しようして、この疑問が生じました。

---

Sentinel については、

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html#Sentinels

によると、 emacs が待機状態のときのみに実行される、とありますが、 process-status がいつ更新されるかの記述が見つからなかったので、質問しています。

Comment: 予測できないと思います. 変わるかもしれないし, 変わらないかもしれない. プロセスの statusが変わるとき, set-process-sentinelで登録したコールバック関数が呼ばれるので状態に気にしたいのであれば, そのコールバック関数内のみで気にするべきだと思います.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

実際には [handle_child_signal (int sig)](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/process.c?h=emacs-25#n6453) で process status の更新を行っています。関数名からも判る通り、`signal(SIGCHLD)` によるソフトウェア割り込みを利用しています。したがって、この関数のコメントにもある通り emacs process が実行中の間はいつでも更新されうるという事になります。

> Handle a SIGCHLD signal by looking for known child processes of Emacs whose status have changed. For each one found, record its new status.
>
> ** WARNING: **this can be called during garbage collection**.
>   Therefore, it must not be fooled by the presence of mark bits in Lisp objects.

Comment: 確認させてください。ソフトウェア割り込みだから、elisp 処理中の任意のタイミングで実行されうる。たとえそれがGC中であっても、ということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、そうです。ただ、言わずもがなだと思いますが、signal handler(こここでは handle_child_signal)の実行中は割り込みを受け付けません。上記のソースコードファイルにコメントとして書かれているかと思いますが、無限ループに陥る危険性があるからです。